# Creating a new version an existing AutoML Model Via Rest ?python

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, vertex-ai-pipeline

I have tried using the json format via rest api and Vertex AI python code as shown in the above image for training a new version of a model, it is giving me the error as in the screenshot error i mentioned.

I have checked the json format as well, and it is not a valid format given in the documentation. The veretx AI SDK is just listing the models in AUTOML.

[image]

[image]

I have tried other ways as well, but didn't find any.